# WebStorm + webpacker debugging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webstorm, webpacker

Hello StackOverflow community!

My team is working on a ruby on rails project, where some parts are written in react. We are using webpacker gem to bundle js files into packs.

I'm trying to set up WebStorm to work with our project, but I have problems with the debugger - webstorm is not hitting any breakpoints. 
I'm launching `rails s` and `./bin/webpack-dev-server` in separate terminal instances, installed chrome extension and created JavaScript Debug configuration, pointing to the view where react app resides (on the port 3000). Also added `devtool: 'eval'` to webpack configuration. In the chrome dev tools I see `webpack://` source and I can successfully set breakpoints there.

How to configure this tooling to have breakpoints working?

Answer (score 0):

normally all you need for debugging apps bundled with webpack is to make sure that sourcemaps are properly generated. The best choice here is `devtool: 'source-map'` (see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/). `eval` sourcemaps are not accurate and not too suitable for debugging (quality is "generated code" rather than "original code").
In some cases, you might also need to specify URL mappings - see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/09/debugging-webpack-applications-in-webstorm/ for more info.
But there are no generic instructions that would work for each and every configuration - as you can configure webpack in dozens of ways. So I can hardly advise on exact steps unless you provide a project you are trying to debug